# Calling external .exe in Windows 8

Tags: java, windows-8, process, runtime.exec

Is it possible that the following code is no longer working when the application is running on windows 8

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("path\\to\\dotexe");
```

On Windows 7 it used to do the job just fine, but on Windows 8 it just wont run the d*rn .exe.

Is there any alternative to this code, or does the not running has to do with user rights on Win8 or something?

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.  *"Kind regards & thanks in advance,
Jeroen."*  Leave such noise out of questions in future.

Comment: Andrew, it appears that it did not work because of spaces in the folder path (which is strange, under Windows 7 it just worked fine). Thanks for the support, I will be able to fix it from here on with String[] args like you said. And the regards were just because I was raised to be polite ;)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  :)